# How to retry HTTP requests with OkHttp/Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I am using Retrofit/OkHttp (1.6) in my Android project.

I don't find any request retry mechanism built-in to either of them. On searching more, I read OkHttp seems to have silent-retries. I don't see that happening on any of my connections (HTTP or HTTPS). How to configure retries with okclient ?

For now, I am catching exceptions and retrying maintaining a counter variable.

Comment: @JesseWilson: I find retrying more useful for slower networks, than longer connection timeouts. Do you think otherwise ?

Comment: sometimes an api will have a response code that will indicate another request needs to be made (to re-up auth tokens, or session tokens or XYZ tokens) and then the original request retried. This is easy to accomplish in Volley. I would love to switch to retrofit, but I don't see a way to accomplish this sort of plumbing in a generic way.

Comment: Did you find out a better method than just catching response exceptions, @SlowAndSteady? I'm currently implementing this on a larger scale and thought my similar method is due for a refactor. Thanks.

Comment: @JoshPinter : Sorry, couldn't find anything else. I am not sure if OhHttp 2.0 has added support for this - you might want to have a look.

Comment: @SlowAndSteady Okay, great, thanks for the update. For the record, I've decided to use a pattern similar to what was outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8658067/293280

Answer (score 104, accepted):

**For Retrofit 2.x;**

You can use [Call.clone()](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html#clone) method to clone request and execute it.

**For Retrofit 1.x;**

You can use [Interceptors](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors). Create a custom interceptor

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    client.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();

            // try the request
            Response response = chain.proceed(request);

            int tryCount = 0;
            while (!response.isSuccessful() && tryCount < 3) {

                Log.d("intercept", "Request is not successful - " + tryCount);

                tryCount++;

                // retry the request
                response.close()
                response = chain.proceed(request);
            }

            // otherwise just pass the original response on
            return response;
        }
    });
```

And use it while creating RestAdapter.

```
new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(API_URL)
        .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
        .setClient(new OkClient(client))
        .build()
        .create(Adapter.class);
```

Comment: when it is timed out on connection, response will be null. With that, how can we check response.isSuccessful() ?

Comment: But is there a way counting the retries? Clone just copies the call so it can be executed again but it doesn't count.

Comment: I config the timeout as 60second.And want to know whether the 60s is all the 1+3retry connection timeout or just one connection's timeout

Comment: When there is no Internet connection, all code after the line `Response response = chain.proceed(request);` will be reachless, because no `Response` will be received.

Comment: you need to do `response.close()` before calling retrying

Comment: How can `call.clone` be used?

Comment: How can `call.clone` be used?

Comment: @malhobayyeb `response = chain.call().clone().execute();`

Comment: I got NullPointer Exception on chain while retrying but only for some requests majority were fine

Answer (score 48):

I don't know if this is an option for you but you could use [RxJava](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava) together with Retrofit.

Retrofit is able to return Observables upon rest calls. On Oberservables you can just call `retry(count)` to resubscribe to the Observable when it emits an error.

You would have to define the call in your interface like this:

```
@GET("/data.json")
Observable<DataResponse> fetchSomeData();
```

Then you can subscribe to this Observable like this:

```
restApi.fetchSomeData()
.retry(5)  // Retry the call 5 times if it errors
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())  // execute the call asynchronously
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())  // handle the results in the ui thread
.subscribe(onComplete, onError); 
// onComplete and onError are of type Action1<DataResponse>, Action1<Throwable>
// Here you can define what to do with the results
```

I had the same problem like you and this was actually my solution. RxJava is a really nice library to use in combination with Retrofit. You can even do many cool things in addition to retrying (like e.g. [composing and chaining calls](http://joluet.github.io/blog/2014/07/07/rxjava-retrofit/)).

Comment: Did you ever try this? It seems like calling retry() (or just subscribing again) on a Retrofit Observable does not actually do the request again.

Comment: @pocmo pls see my response, maybe it will help

Answer (score 26):

I am of the opinion that you shouldn't mix API handling (done by retrofit/okhttp) with retries. Retrying mechanisms are more orthogonal, and can be used in many other contexts as well. So I use Retrofit/OkHTTP for all the API calls and request/response handling, and introduce another layer above, for retrying the API call.

In my limited Java experience so far, I have found jhlaterman's Failsafe library (github: [jhalterman/failsafe](https://github.com/jhalterman/failsafe)) to be a very versatile library for handling many 'retry' situations cleanly. As an example, here's how I would use it with a retrofit instantiated mySimpleService, for authentication -

```
AuthenticationResponse authResp = Failsafe.with(
new RetryPolicy().retryOn(Arrays.asList(IOException.class, AssertionError.class))
        .withBackoff(30, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .withMaxRetries(3))
.onRetry((error) -> logger.warn("Retrying after error: " + error.getMessage()))
.get(() -> {
    AuthenticationResponse r = mySimpleAPIService.authenticate(
            new AuthenticationRequest(username,password))
            .execute()
            .body();

    assert r != null;

    return r;
});
```

The code above catches socket exceptions, connection errors, assertion failures, and retries on them maximum of 3 times, with exponential backoff. It also allows you to customise on-retry behaviour, and allows you to specify a fallback as well. It's quite configurable, and can adapt to most of the retry situations.

Feel free to check the documentation of the library as it offers many other goodies apart from just retries.

Comment: Instructive from a design perspective to point out the orthogonal nature of API call+handling vs retrying the calls - one sits at a higher level than the other.

Comment: This is pretty cool but the current version `2.3.1` seems to require API 26 due to the time units used (ChronoUnit)

Comment: @behelit And what's the problem? API 26 was more then 2 years old whe you wrote your comment (released in August 2017). Most of the serious Android developers I know distribute their app by Google Play. If you want to use Play you have to keep SDK/API level up to date... Google forced you to use API 26 since August 2018 for new apps and since November 2018 for updates of existing apps.

Answer (score 15):

The problem with response.isSuccessful() is when you have an exception like SocketTimeoutException.

I modified the original code to fix it.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
client.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Response response = null;
        boolean responseOK = false;
        int tryCount = 0;

        while (!responseOK && tryCount < 3) {
            try {
                 response = chain.proceed(request);
                 responseOK = response.isSuccessful();                  
            }catch (Exception e){
                 Log.d("intercept", "Request is not successful - " + tryCount);                     
            }finally{
                 tryCount++;      
            }
        }

        // otherwise just pass the original response on
        return response;
    }
});
```

Hope it helps. 
Regards.

Comment: But this will retry even if server is down or any other case

Comment: It crashes when internet is not available. I am trying request over SSL, adding custom headers and added one other logging interceptor.

Comment: If we have timeout or no connection, it returns null and then it generate NullPointerException

Comment: `OkHttpClient` does not have a `setConnectTimeout` method, and `interceptors()` is immutable. Could it be that this answer is based on an old version? I am using <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: To fix nullPointerException (when there is no internet connection as people mentioned above) need to replace ```return response;``` at the end with ```return response != null ? response : chain.proceed(request);```

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr OkHttpClient.Builder().readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

Comment: @oxied This doesn't make any sense. You add just another request which will fail again and the response stays null.

Answer (score 4):

Courtesy to the top answer,This is what worked for me. If there is a connectivity issues, its better to wait for a few seconds before retry.

```
public class ErrorInterceptor implements Interceptor {
ICacheManager cacheManager;
Response response = null;
int tryCount = 0;
int maxLimit = 3;
int waitThreshold = 5000;
@Inject
public ErrorInterceptor() {

}

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain){

   // String language =  cacheManager.readPreference(PreferenceKeys.LANGUAGE_CODE);
  Request request = chain.request();
  response =  sendReqeust(chain,request);
    while (response ==null && tryCount < maxLimit) {
        Log.d("intercept", "Request failed - " + tryCount);
        tryCount++;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(waitThreshold); // force wait the network thread for 5 seconds
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       response = sendReqeust(chain,request);
    }
    return response;
}

private Response sendReqeust(Chain chain, Request request){
    try {
        response = chain.proceed(request);
        if(!response.isSuccessful())
            return null;
        else
        return response;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you help me?? when server is giving error 500 or others it doesn't work  -->HTTP FAILED: java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot make a new request because the previous response is still open

Answer (score 3):

A solution that worked for me on OkHttp 3.9.1 (considering other answers for this question):

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request  request      = chain.request();
    int      retriesCount = 0;
    Response response     = null;

    do {
        try {
            response = chain.proceed(request);

        // Retry if no internet connection.
        } catch (ConnectException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "intercept: ", e);
            retriesCount++;

            try {
                Thread.sleep(RETRY_TIME);

            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                Log.e(TAG, "intercept: ", e1);
            }
        }

    } while (response == null && retriesCount < MAX_RETRIES);

    // If there was no internet connection, then response will be null.
    // Need to initialize response anyway to avoid NullPointerException.
    if (response == null) {
        response = chain.proceed(newRequest);
    }

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the way(OKHttpClient intercepter) provided by Sinan Kozak does not work when http connection failed, there is nothing yet concerned with HTTP response.

So i use another way to hook the Observable object, call .retryWhen on it.
Also, i have added retryCount limit.

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.CallAdapter;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.HttpException;
import retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory;
import retrofit2.converter.jackson.JacksonConverterFactory;
import rx.Observable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
```

Then

```
    RxJavaCallAdapterFactory originCallAdaptorFactory = RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create();

    CallAdapter.Factory newCallAdaptorFactory = new CallAdapter.Factory() {
        @Override
        public CallAdapter<?> get(Type returnType, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {

            CallAdapter<?> ca = originCallAdaptorFactory.get(returnType, annotations, retrofit);

            return new CallAdapter<Observable<?>>() {

                @Override
                public Type responseType() {
                    return ca.responseType();
                }

                int restRetryCount = 3;

                @Override
                public <R> Observable<?> adapt(Call<R> call) {
                    Observable<?> rx = (Observable<?>) ca.adapt(call);

                    return rx.retryWhen(errors -> errors.flatMap(error -> {
                        boolean needRetry = false;
                        if (restRetryCount >= 1) {
                            if (error instanceof IOException) {
                                needRetry = true;
                            } else if (error instanceof HttpException) {
                                if (((HttpException) error).code() != 200) {
                                    needRetry = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (needRetry) {
                            restRetryCount--;
                            return Observable.just(null);
                        } else {
                            return Observable.error(error);
                        }
                    }));
                }
            };
        }
    };
```

Then 
   add or replace

```
.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
```

with

```
.addCallAdapterFactory(newCallAdaptorFactory)
```

For example:

```
return new Retrofit
        .Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .client(okClient)
        .addCallAdapterFactory(newCallAdaptorFactory)
        .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(objectMapper));
```

Note: For simplicity, i just treat HTTP code > 404 code as retry, please modify it for yourself.

Besides, if http response is 200, then above `rx.retryWhen` will not get called, if you insist check such a response, you can add `rx.subscribeOn(...throw error...` before .retryWhen.

Answer (score 2):

For those prefer an interceptor to deal with the issue of retrying -
Building upon Sinan's answer, here is my proposed interceptor, which includes both retry count and back-off delay, and only retries attempts when network is available, and when request wasn't cancelled.
(only deals with IOExceptions (SocketTimeout, UnknownHost, etc.))

```
    builder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();

            // try the request
            Response response = null;
            int tryCount = 1;
            while (tryCount <= MAX_TRY_COUNT) {
                try {
                    response = chain.proceed(request);
                    break;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    if (!NetworkUtils.isNetworkAvailable()) {
                        // if no internet, dont bother retrying request
                        throw e;
                    }
                    if ("Canceled".equalsIgnoreCase(e.getMessage())) {
                        // Request canceled, do not retry
                        throw e;
                    }
                    if (tryCount >= MAX_TRY_COUNT) {
                        // max retry count reached, giving up
                        throw e;
                    }

                    try {
                        // sleep delay * try count (e.g. 1st retry after 3000ms, 2nd after 6000ms, etc.)
                        Thread.sleep(RETRY_BACKOFF_DELAY * tryCount);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e1);
                    }
                    tryCount++;
                }
            }

            // otherwise just pass the original response on
            return response;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have play a lot with this problem trying to find how is the best way to retry Retrofit requests. I am using Retrofit 2 so my solution is for Retrofit 2. For Retrofit 1 you have to use Interceptor like the accepted answer here. The answer of @joluet is correct but he did not mention that  retry method need to be called before .subscribe(onComplete, onError) method. This is very important otherwise the request wouldn't be retried again like @pocmo mentioned in @joluet answer. Here is my example:

```
final Observable<List<NewsDatum>> newsDetailsObservable = apiService.getCandidateNewsItem(newsId).map((newsDetailsParseObject) -> {
                    return newsDetailsParseObject;
                });

newsDetailsObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .retry((integer, throwable) -> {
                //MAX_NUMBER_TRY is your maximum try number
                if(integer <= MAX_NUMBER_TRY){
                    return true;//this will retry the observable (request)
                }
                return false;//this will not retry and it will go inside onError method
            })
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<NewsDatum>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    // do nothing
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                   //do something with the error
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<NewsDatum> apiNewsDatum) {
                    //do something with the parsed data
                }
            });
```

apiService  is my RetrofitServiceProvider object.

BTW : I am using Java 8 so a lot of lambda expressions are inside the code.

Comment: I have done this, and according to my logs, retrofitl only call network once. There is something wrong with this method!

Answer (score 1):

Just want to share my version. It uses rxJava retryWhen method. My version retries connection every N=15 sec and almost immediately emit retry when internet connection recover.

```
public class RetryWithDelayOrInternet implements Function<Flowable<? extends Throwable>, Flowable<?>> {
public static boolean isInternetUp;
private int retryCount;

@Override
public Flowable<?> apply(final Flowable<? extends Throwable> attempts) {
    return Flowable.fromPublisher(s -> {
        while (true) {
            retryCount++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                attempts.subscribe(s);
                break;
            }
            if (isInternetUp || retryCount == 15) {
                retryCount = 0;
                s.onNext(new Object());
            }
        }
    })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single());
}}
```

And you should use it before .subscribe like this:

```
.retryWhen(new RetryWithDelayOrInternet())
```

You should manually change isInternetUp field

```
public class InternetConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    boolean networkAvailable = isNetworkAvailable(context);
    RetryWithDelayOrInternet.isInternetUp = networkAvailable;
}
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a previous user said, if your are using Retrofit2 call.clone would suffice, but I also wanted to add a quick example on how that would look:

```
public class CallbackImpl implements Callback<ResponseBody> {
    private final Set<Integer> retryCode = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(503, 504));
    int requestRetry  = 1;

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        if (response.code() == 201) {
            // Object was created.
        } else {
            if (requestRetry != 0 && retryCode.contains(response.code())) {
                call.clone().enqueue(this);
            } else {
                // Handle the error
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable throwable) {
        if (throwable instanceof IOException) {
            // Network failure
        } else {
            // Conversion Issue
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Resilience4j 1.x offered a highly configurable way of defining your retry behaviour and has retrofit adapters as an add-on module. **This functionality has since been deprecated in version 2.0**.

Example of the available options:

```
private final Retry retry = Retry.of("id", RetryConfig.<Response<String>>custom()
  .maxAttempts(2)
  .waitDuration(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
  .retryOnResult(response -> response.code() == 500)
  .retryOnException(e -> e instanceof WebServiceException)
  .retryExceptions(IOException.class, TimeoutException.class)
  .ignoreExceptions(BusinessException.class, OtherBusinessException.class)
  .failAfterMaxAttempts(true)
  .build());
```

See [the resilience4j documentation](https://resilience4j.readme.io/v1.7.0/docs/retrofit#retry) on how to integrate that with Retrofit.

Comment: The link leads to "404 Not Found" page.

Comment: @VladimirKattsyn looks like this has been deprecated. I modified my answer accordingly and linked the old documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it will be present in retrofit 2.0 from the API Spec:
https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/297.
Currently, the best way seems to be catch exception and retry manually.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [docs](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes), a better might be to use the baked in authenticators, eg:
private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

```
  public void run() throws Exception {
    client.setAuthenticator(new Authenticator() {
      @Override public Request authenticate(Proxy proxy, Response response) {
        System.out.println("Authenticating for response: " + response);
        System.out.println("Challenges: " + response.challenges());
        String credential = Credentials.basic("jesse", "password1");
        return response.request().newBuilder()
            .header("Authorization", credential)
            .build();
      }

      @Override public Request authenticateProxy(Proxy proxy, Response response) {
        return null; // Null indicates no attempt to authenticate.
      }
    });

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://publicobject.com/secrets/hellosecret.txt")
        .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

    System.out.println(response.body().string());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Working prod solution.

```
public int callAPI() {
    return 1; //some method to be retried
}

public int retrylogic()  throws InterruptedException, IOException{
    int retry = 0;
    int status = -1;
    boolean delay = false;
    do {
        if (delay) {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }

        try {
            status = callAPI();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error occured");
            status = -1;
        }
        finally {
            switch (status) {
            case 200:
                System.out.println(" **OK**");
                return status; 
            default:
                System.out.println(" **unknown response code**.");
                break;
            }
            retry++;
            System.out.println("Failed retry " + retry + "/" + 3);
            delay = true;

        } 
    }while (retry < 3);

    System.out.println("Aborting download of dataset.");
    return status;
}
```