# Okhttp - OkHttpClient 2.0.0 cannot resolve method interceptor()

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

Im using Retrofit 1.9.0 together with OkHttp 2.0.0

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
```

but interceptor method is not found on it

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.setConnectTimeout(50000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
client.setReadTimeout(50000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
client.interceptor().add(...); // cannot resolve method interceptor
```

I'm currently dealing with retry-request on retrofit, suggested from this post
[How to retry HTTP requests with OkHttp/Retrofit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562716/how-to-retry-http-requests-with-okhttp-retrofit)

am i missing some libraries here?

Comment: OkHttp 2.0.0 is what my grandfather used. You want the latest: OkHttp 3.0.0-RC1 is best as of today.

Answer (score 7):

try like this:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta3'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
```

in your Client class:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(
                    new Interceptor() {
                        @Override
                        public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                            Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                            return chain.proceed(request);
                        }
                    })
            .build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    restAPI = retrofit.create(RestAPI.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Also IMHO use retrofit 2.0 (although its still in beta, in my opinion its mature enough). You can

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit-converters:2.0.0-beta3'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta3'
```

Also for both 1.9 and 2, There are excellent series of blogs which I found useful in my learning Retrofit better. You can find them [here](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client)

**Edit:** Since Retrofit 2 relies on OkHttp for network operations, you will not need to add OkHttp dependency explicitly once you have added the retrofit2