# okhttp connection tries and connect time

Tags: android, networking, okhttp

I have a small trouble with okhttp.

1. How to set a connect time (for ex. 10 sec and this 10 sec okhttp lib should try to get a response from server)?
2. How to set a connect tries (for ex. when this 10 sec is ended)?

Answer (score 0):

```
        client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.setConnectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        client.setReadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        client.setWriteTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Please explain your solution.

Comment: you can set the connect time (timeout) using the code above.

To retry request please create a custom interceptor 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562716/how-to-retry-http-requests-with-okhttp-retrofit