# Retrofit: How do I retry the request again from okhttp interceptor?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp, interceptor

Ive created an interceptor. In some cases, I want to retry the request 'n' number of time how do i do this?

```
class NetworkErrorHandler constructor():  Interceptor {

    //Central error handling block for errors which has impact all over the app
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request =  chain.request()
        var response = chain.proceed(request) 

        return  
            when (response.code) {
                401 -> { 
                    response
                }
                200 ->{  
                    response
                }
                else -> { 
                        var tryCount = 0
                        while (tryCount < 3) {
                            try { 
                                response = chain.proceed(request)
                                tryCount++
                            }catch (e: java.lang.Exception){
                                tryCount++
                            }
                        }  
                    response
                }
            } 
    }
}
```

It gives me this error:

```
Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: network interceptor must call proceed() exactly once
```

Do I have to do this here if yes, then how?

Comment: i guess we can't: https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/network-interceptors/

Answer (score 5):

Use `.interceptors()` to use `Application Interceptor` instead of `.networkInterceptors()` which are allowed to call `.proceed()` more than once.
[image]
More information: https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/

Answer (score 2):

This is how I approached it:

```
@Slf4j
public class HttpRetryInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public @NotNull Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        log.error("Making request for the first time.");
        var request = chain.request();
        Response response = null;
        boolean responseOK = false;
        byte tryCount = 0;
        while (!responseOK && tryCount < 3) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000 * tryCount);
                response = chain.proceed(request);
                log.info("Response is: {}",response);
                log.info("Response message: {}",response.message());
                responseOK = response.isSuccessful();

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                log.error("Request was not successful: {} . Retrying." , tryCount);
            }finally{
                assert response != null;
                response.close();
                tryCount++;
            }
        }

        return response != null ? response : chain.proceed(request);
    }
}
```

And then I added my Interceptor to my client with something like : `new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new HttpRetryInterceptor()).build()`

Answer (score 1):

So i was able to make another call from the interceptor by using this line

```
response.close()      
chain.call().clone().execute()
```

Full code according to the question:

```
//Central error handling block for errors which has impact all over the app
class NetworkErrorHandler constructor(): Interceptor {

        var tryCount = 0
        override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
            val request = chain.request()
            var response = chain.proceed(request)

            return
            when(response.code) {
                401 - > {
                    response
                }
                200 - > {
                    response
                }
                else - > {

                    if (tryCount < 3) {
                        Thread.sleep(2000)
                        tryCount++
                        response.close()
                        chain.call().clone().execute()

                    }
                    response.newBuilder()
                    .code(401) // Whatever code
                    .body("".toResponseBody(null)) // Whatever body
                    .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_2)
                    .message("Network Error")
                    .request(chain.request())
                    .build()
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you guided yourself from this other question [How to retry HTTP requests with OkHttp/Retrofit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562716/how-to-retry-http-requests-with-okhttp-retrofit) (If not, I suggest you do). The problem on your code is that your while is restricted only by trycount, but not by the result of the response. Try adding the validation regarding the status of the response in there too, so it doesn't execute the .proceed method two times in parallel.

```
// try the request
Response response = chain.proceed(request);

int tryCount = 0;
while (!response.isSuccessful() && tryCount < 3) {
```

Comment: im able to make request again with help of this line:
response = chain.call().clone().execute()

Comment: it is restricted by the status code of the response.code other than the tryCount.

Comment: The solution on the first comment is possible, but you will end up having 3 calls to the service, if that's ok for you then perfect.

Comment: For the restriction, I mean on the while per se, not between the first call and the call inside the while, I'm not sure of it but I think the compiler gets to see that there is no restriction to execute the while again, while if you place the response the compiler knows that it has to wait for the call to be finished before continuing with the next iteration

Comment: i see your point, isn't it better to remove the while and just use if. please see my answer below.

Comment: I get this error now:  FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher  HTTP FAILED: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: networkResponse.networkResponse != null

Comment: does this works in `networkInterceptor`?