# java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot make a new request because the previous response is still open: please call response.close()

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit

[image]This is the interceptor code i cant figure out where to call the response.close() on the logCat it states that the error appears on the "response = chain.proceed(request). Where do i place the response.close() call or do i use closeQuietly()

class AppInterceptor:Interceptor {

```
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
    var request = chain.request()

      try{
          var response = chain.proceed(request)
          var tryCount = 0
          val maxTries = 5

        while (!response.isSuccessful && tryCount < maxTries){
            tryCount++
            Thread.sleep(1500)
            request = request.newBuilder().build()
            response = chain.proceed(request)

        }
        return response

      }catch (e: Exception){
        e.printStackTrace()
        val message: String

        when (e){
            is SocketTimeoutException ->{
                message = Constants.SOCKET_TIMEOUT
            }

            is UnknownHostException ->{
                message = Constants.UNKNOWN_HOST
            }

            is ConnectionShutdownException ->{
                message = Constants.CONNECTION_SHUTDOWN
            }

            is IOException ->{
                message = Constants.IO_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE
            }

            is IllegalStateException ->{
                message = "${e.message}"
            }
            else ->{
                message = "${e.message}"
            }
        }
        return Response.Builder()
            .request(request)
            .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
            .code(999)
            .message(message)
            .body("{${e}".toResponseBody(null))
            .build()
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You should close just before you call `chain.proceed(request)` method
so your code will be like this

```
while (!response.isSuccessful && tryCount < maxTries){
            tryCount++
            request = request.newBuilder().build()
            response.close() // here you need to add
            response = chain.proceed(request)

        }
```

For more information , you can see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31733634/5696047

I am not aware why you have added `Thread.sleep(1500)` but I don't think it is required

Comment: I added the response.close() as you wrote I get a different error A RESPONSE FAILED TO CLOSE

Comment: Can you update your question with that error stacktrace

Comment: i added an image from my LogCAT